# EasyBCD, Windows 8 Bootloader, and GRUB2 Help?

Tags: 12.10, grub2, dual-boot, windows-8, easybcd

Basically I've dual booted windows 8 and ubuntu 12.10 using this guide: 
http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/11/05/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-hardware/1/

It all works perfectly but there are 2 minor things I dislike and cannot change:

1. On the Windows 8 Dual Boot screen, as seen in the link I posted on image 1, there are 2 options, windows 8 and ubuntu, each with its own icon; now windows 8 has its own logo but ubuntu has a crappy window, wondering how to change this to my own metro icon for ubuntu?
2. After clicking the option for ubuntu, I go straight into Grub2, asking me to choose a boot option again, how would I go about editing GRUB2 and changing the timeout to 0.

Comment: Please indicate your BootInfo URL: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I'd like an answer to the first question as well.

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/499617/how-can-i-add-linux-to-the-new-windows-8-boot-manager

Answer (score 1):

I do not have an answer to your first question. In any case, on this site it is recommended to ask ONE question at a time.

Regarding the second, you can update grub by typing in a terminal `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub` Change the line `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`. Then run `sudo update-grub`.

If in the future you need to access the grub menu, press shift and the menu should show.

Comment: Thankyou, i will in the future only ask one to stop confusion, yup seems to be skipping GRUB2, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The guide provided by the link is for BIOS/MBR installation.

(http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/11/05/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-hardware/1/)

IT IS NOT FOR UEFI/GPT !

People are writing tutorials without understanding basic things:

1. Loaders for EFI/GPT have .efi extension not .exe !
2. There are no logical partitions on GPT disks !

Complete bullshit.

I think this is cheap EasyBCD spamming.